# Why can't we use the verb 'reveal' in the following sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice

In this 'spot the word that doesn't fit' question I am not clear as to the reason why revealed is not correct - something related to passives perhaps?

'As details of the scandal _______ , the story became a big news item.'
Which of these cannot be used:
Revealed/Emerged/Surfaced/Unfolded

Comment: "Revealed" is a transitive verb -- the thing revealed is the "object", while the entity doing the revealing is the "subject".

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. But I have to say, the difference is very difficult to explain to someone unfamiliar with grammatical concepts. I know that issue is not the purpose of this platform, and perhaps it's a rabbit hole - but I'm always curious as to how we can bridge that gap. I think the transitive/intransitive aspect of grammar is especially complex. Do you know if this is something common to most languages?

Comment: Depending on the test, answers may be expected not to be totally and undeniably correct, but simply just better than others. Of those 4, even though 'revealed' works perfectly fine grammatically and semantically, it is not like the others.